# Colorbox resize not working, returns "TypeError: $.fn.colorbox is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox version 1.3 and called colorbox with a following code

```
 $(".extractImages").colorbox({
    ajax:true,
    speed:100,
    initialWidth:'110px', 
    initialHeight:'85px',
    rel:'popup',
    fixed:true,
    arrowKey:false,
    href:function(){ 
        return $(this).attr('popup'); 
    },
    onLoad: function() {
        $('#cboxClose').html('');
        $('#cboxCurrent').remove();
        $('#cboxNext').remove();
        $('#cboxPrevious').remove();
        $('#cboxTitle').remove();
    },  
    onComplete : function() {
        $('#cboxClose').html('<img class="popupClose" src="/public/images/close.png"/>');
        $.fn.colorbox.resize();             
    }
  });
```

As you can see I have called resize method on complete but it gives me following error

```
TypeError: $.fn.colorbox is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

$.fn.colorbox.resize();
```

I have also tried the following:

```
TypeError: $(".extractImages").colorbox is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

$('.extractImages').colorbox.resize();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
onComplete : function() { 
$(this).colorbox.resize(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox%20%22Colorbox) says under 'Public Methods': $.colorbox.resize() . I'd give that a go.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `colorbox` was loaded? looks like you don't include `jquery.colorbox.js` on the page. This `$.colorbox` must show `function()` in console.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
        $.colorbox.resize({
            maxWidth:"auto",
            width:95+'%',
        });
});
```